# Link or a Javascript snippet Open external app from a link on the android captive portal browser

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, filter

I need to open android application from captive portal browser but I am not able to achieve it with `intent://scan/#Intent`(intent scan), it results in

> net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

is there anyother way to achievve it?

Comment: the question is relating to the android captive portal browser.

Comment: Have you tried using App links - https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/

Comment: yes, it is not supported in the captive portal browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mobile deep links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_deep_linking) for this. If the App you are using implements deep links, this is what you normally use.

```
appname://path/to/action
```

- https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking
- https://www.apptamin.com/blog/mobile-deep-linking/
- https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e
- https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/

Comment: App links are not on the Captive portal Browser : I raised a captive portal browser bug with the Android dev team here : https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/124306193

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same requirement with your question. But it is likely that we shouldn't launch a Android app from browser. The reason is the intent filters may be difference between different Android versions. And it looks like that Android is trying to restrict it. On Android 6.0 (API level 23) and higher allow an app to designate itself as the default handler of a given type of link. If the user doesn't want the app to be the default handler, they can override this behavior from their device's system settings(https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/#app-links-vs-deep-links)

Comment: App links are not on the Captive portal Browser : I raised a captive portal browser bug with the Android dev team here : https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/124306193